# Razor view MVC 5 JavaScript - resolve document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Migrating my MVC3 (aspx) project to MVC5 (razor), I use:

```
                <% if ((bool)this.ViewData["ReadOnly"] != true)
                   { %>
                    document.getElementById("NextAction").value = nextAction;
                    document.getElementById("VisitForm").submit();
                <% } else { %>
                    window.location = nextAction;
                <% } %>
```

I modified it to:

```
                     @if ((bool)this.ViewData["ReadOnly"] != true)
                     {
                       document.getElementById("NextAction").value = nextAction;
                       document.getElementById("VisitForm").submit();
                     } else {  
                        window.location = nextAction;
                     }
```

Can not resolve either document or window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC uses HTML tags to enter/exit parsing of the template automatically. In your previous version you were fully wrapped in `<%  %>` tags to identify when server side parsing should be active. Razor syntax doesn't rely on that specifically anymore, but instead will exit server side parsing when it encounters an HTML tag and re-enters it when it encounters the closing version of the tag. Try wrapping your JavaScript inside `<text>` tags to identify for the template parser that raw "HTML" is coming:

```
@if ((bool)this.ViewData["ReadOnly"] != true)
{
    <text>
    document.getElementById("NextAction").value = nextAction;
    document.getElementById("VisitForm").submit();
    </text>
} else {  
    <text>
    window.location = nextAction;
    </text>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing script tags.  Like so:

```
@if ((bool)this.ViewData["ReadOnly"] != true)
{
    <script>
        document.getElementById("NextAction").value = nextAction;
        document.getElementById("VisitForm").submit();
    </script>

}
else
{
    <script>
        window.location = nextAction;
    </script>

}
```

Comment: You'd do well to remove the Stack Snippet from this answer; they only work for HTML, CSS and JS, not ASP.NET MVC. Otherwise, good answer